# Performance of marker on-click event is bad

Tags: angularjs-google-maps

I have a problem with the performance of a click event on a marker.

This is my map view:

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <map center="{{mapCenter}}" street-view-control="false" zoom-control="false" map-type-control="false" zoom="14">
        <marker position="{{place.coords}}" title="{{place.name}}" icon="{{place.icon}}" ng-repeat="place in places" on-click="select(place.id)"></marker>
    </map>
</div>
```

This is a button calling the same function (same view and controller):

```
<button ng-click="select(null, 13)">My test button</button>
```

This is my function:

```
$scope.select = function(event, placeId) {
  $log.debug('select called');
  $location.path('/places/' + placeId);
};
```

When I click on the button the console.log appears and location change happens immediately. When I click on the marker the console.log appears immediately but the location change takes up to 5s to happen.

Any idea how this could be?

Comment: Could you add a plnkr for this? I will take a look at it. FYI, the event used on map is pure google maps V3 event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case calling $digest() on $scope in a timeout function did the trick:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid ng-repeat use ui-gmap-markers instead in which it has a click param to wire up your handler.